# Is there a better way to get consecutive year-month values count in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, row-number

My data is like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ym': [202012,   202009, 202012, 202101, 202103, 202104, 202012, 202101, 202102, 202103, 202105, 202009, 202012, 202101, 202011, 202104], 'user_id': ['049', '009',  '009',  '009',  '009',  '009',  '130',  '130',  '130',  '130',  '130',  '166',  '166',  '166',  '282',  '282']})
df
```

```
ym  user_id
0   202012  049
1   202009  009
2   202012  009
3   202101  009
4   202103  009
5   202104  009
6   202012  130
7   202101  130
8   202102  130
9   202103  130
10  202105  130
11  202009  166
12  202012  166
13  202101  166
14  202011  282
15  202104  282
```

I want to count
apearances on year-month leave for each user, and I have tried this nasty way to get that:

```
#get a shift column of current year month column
df['ym_s'] = df.sort_values(['user_id','ym']).groupby('user_id')['ym'].shift(-1)
df = df.sort_values(['user_id','ym'])

#get diff value of year month 
df['cntn_vl'] = df['ym_s']- df['ym']

#pick out the consecutive part of in my data: normal consecutive month = 1 or dec-jan value
df['rank'] = np.where(df['cntn_vl'].isin([1,89]), 1, 0)

#finally aggregate the consecutive appearance of each user
df_1 = df.groupby(by =['user_id'],as_index=False)['rank'].sum()
df_1
```

```
user_id rank
0   009 2
1   049 0
2   130 3
3   166 1
4   282 0
```

My question is, is there a better/fast(in my billions rows data, it's so hard to run) way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['user_id','ym'])

df['rank'] = df.groupby('user_id')['ym'].diff().isin([1,89])
#finally aggregate the consecutive appearance of each user
df_1 = df.groupby('user_id',as_index=False)['rank'].sum()
```

Or custom lambda function for avoid double `groupby`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['user_id','ym'])

f = lambda x: x.diff().isin([1,89]).sum()
#numpy alternative should be faster
#f = lambda x: np.in1d(np.diff(x),[1,89]).sum()
df_1 = df.groupby('user_id')['ym'].agg(f).reset_index(name='rank')

print (df_1)
  user_id  rank
0     009     2
1     049     0
2     130     3
3     166     1
4     282     0
```

Comment: more straightforward, thanks!
I haven't precisely benchmark the speed of your way, but when I have tried in my data, it seems more slow. Anyway, it is a good way to catch the problem with your method then